# Data Import and cells as variables with quantities

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I would like to import txt file with not even row length and each row containing variable name with occurrence quantity or without any variables - just ID. Every column is separated by space.

The sample data looks like:

```
V1   V2   Variables:Qty
1234 0001 38571:20
1235 0007 83744:1 74572:12 29401:12
8485 1284 74572:1 38571:16
9412 8310
```

What I need to achieve is presented below:

```
V1   V2   38571 83744 74572 29401
1234 0001 20    0     0     0
1235 0007 0     1     12    12
8485 1284 16    0     1     0
9412 8310 0     0     0     0
```

Data file is quite big, containing over 8000 rows and 600 unique variables (XXXXX:X), as mentioned before every column in separated by space.

If anyone have some suggestions how to do it please advise. I thought of any of dplyr/tidyr but go no sensible idea how to solve it.

Edit:
Raw data file:

```
1234 0001 38571:20
1235 0007 83744:1 74572:12 29401:12
8485 1284 74572:1 38571:16
9412 8310
```

I load it with below code:

```
data <- data.table(read.table("data.txt", sep = " ", fill = TRUE))
```

and my *data.frame* have 5 columns

```
  V1   V2       V3       V4       V5
1: 1234    1 38571:20                  
2: 1235    7  83744:1 74572:12 29401:12
3: 8485 1284  74572:1 38571:16         
4: 9412 8310
```

I have one more problem, after importing my actual data with code above R makes 26 variables only whereas it should make over 50 columns (remaining 24 vars are treated as new row what makes absolutely no sense). I believe it is issue of options for length.

Comment: SO specifies single questions and strongly suggest [MCVE]S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` & `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  separate_rows(Variables.Qty, sep = ' ') %>% 
  separate(Variables.Qty, c('Variables','Qty'), sep = ':') %>% 
  spread(Variables, Qty, fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-7)
```

The result:

```
    V1   V2 29401 38571 74572 83744
1 1234 0001     0    20     0     0
2 1235 0007    12     0    12     1
3 8485 1284     0    16     1     0
4 9412 8310     0     0     0     0
```

---

For the updated data:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
rawdata %>% 
  gather(key, val, 3:5) %>% 
  separate(val, c('Variables','Qty'), sep = ':') %>% 
  mutate(Qty = as.numeric(Qty)) %>% 
  spread(Variables, Qty, fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(key = parse_number(key), key = cumsum(key < lag(key, default = 0))) %>% 
  select(-8) %>% 
  group_by(V1, V2, key) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum) %>% 
  select(-key)
```

The result:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
Groups: V1, V2 [4]

     V1    V2 `29401` `38571` `74572` `83744`
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1  1234  0001       0      20       0       0
2  1235  0007      12       0      12       1
3  8485  1284       0      16       1       0
4  9412  8310       0       0       0       0
```

---

Data used in this answer:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="V1   V2   Variables:Qty
                        1234 0001 '38571:20'
                        1235 0007 '83744:1 74572:12 29401:12'
                        8485 1284 '74572:1 38571:16'
                        9412 8310 ''",
                  header=TRUE, colClasses='character')

rawdata <- read.table(text="1234 0001 38571:20
                            1235 0007 83744:1 74572:12 29401:12
                            8485 1284 74572:1 38571:16
                            9412 8310",
                      header=FALSE, colClasses='character', fill=TRUE, na.strings='')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I edited my post. The point is I got not 3 columns but 5 but your solution got me idea to marge columns and than run your code - the another problem is R makes only 26 variables for my actual data, I think it is caused by some options setting related to txt file.

Comment: @Maniek I have updated my answer. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your solution - I think it is scalable and will work but I have problem with importing final data. It looks like R can import only limited number of variables/characters from txt file (as I counted 250 characters each row - 26 variables in my case), rest variables are moved to new row - it does not make any sense in data. After I solve this strange issue I will confirm your solution works.